# Terraform Unable to create backup of EC2 for Selecting Backups By Tag

Tags: terraform, aws-backup

I have a `Terraform` resource that creates a backup of an EC2 instance in `AWS Backup`. I am trying to choose my instances based on `tags`. So by referring to `Terraform docs` online ([Selecting Backups By Tag](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/backup_selection#selecting-backups-by-tag)), I created a resource that looks as below:

```
resource "aws_backup_selection" "select_lin_config" {
iam_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::abc"
name         = "lin_config"
plan_id      = aws_backup_plan.bkp_plan_ec2.id

selection_tag {
  type  = "STRINGEQUALS"
  key   = "Name"
  value = "config_lin1"
 } 
}
```

When I do a `terraform apply`, I am getting below error:

```
Error: error creating Backup Selection: InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid selection conditions Condition(conditionType=STRINGEQUALS, conditionKey=Name, conditionValue=config_lin1)
{
  RespMetadata: {
StatusCode: 400,

RequestID: "587a331c-e218-4341-9de1-a69a3ef7ec21"
  },
  Code_: "ERROR_3309",
  Context: "Condition(conditionType=STRINGEQUALS, conditionKey=Name, conditionValue=config_lin1)",
  Message_: "Invalid selection conditions Condition(conditionType=STRINGEQUALS, conditionKey=Name, conditionValue=config_lin1)"
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you code that you provided here. Maybe its due to TF version or aws provider that you use? Are you using latest versions?

Comment: Terraform v0.13.5

+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.23.0

These are the version details @Marcin

Comment: Are you sure that the code in the question is fully representative representation of your real code?

Comment: Not exactly the same. I have changed IAM ARN, and `value` of `selection_tag` in this post. Rest all, the code remains same to my actual code @Marcin.

Comment: The code is correct. Maybe the issue is with the role or your backup plan?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following example almost as it is from Terraform documentation and it worked. Copy and paste the following into your Terraform code and try it out.

Just to be sure, you might want to upgrade the AWS provider to the latest version using `terraform init -upgrade`. My AWS provider version is 3.26.0.

```
resource "aws_backup_vault" "example" {
  name        = "example_backup_vault"
}

resource "aws_backup_plan" "example" {
  name = "tf_example_backup_plan"

  rule {
    rule_name         = "tf_example_backup_rule"
    target_vault_name = aws_backup_vault.example.name
    schedule          = "cron(0 12 * * ? *)"
  }

  advanced_backup_setting {
    backup_options = {
      WindowsVSS = "enabled"
    }
    resource_type = "EC2"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name               = "example"
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"],
      "Effect": "allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["backup.amazonaws.com"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "example" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup"
  role       = aws_iam_role.example.name
}

resource "aws_backup_selection" "example" {
  iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  name         = "tf_example_backup_selection"
  plan_id      = aws_backup_plan.example.id

  selection_tag {
    type  = "STRINGEQUALS"
    key   = "foo"
    value = "bar"
  }
}
```